# Which php.ini is used on my system?

Tags: magento2, php, php-7

I'm using Magento 2.3.0 with **PHP 7.2.15-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (cli) (built: Feb  8 2019 14:54:22) ( NTS )**, and I'm not sure which is the **php.ini** file that I should modify. I am currently modifying these two with the same information:

- /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini
- /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini

But I guess the system only use one of the two, where can I check which of the two files is the one using the system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I want to clarify the difference, as the 2 files are not redundant and you may still need to modify both files in most cases. Especially since sometimes, we use the command line to run some Magento commands.

As the other answers mention, running `phpinfo()` will let you know which `php.ini` file you would be using. However, the two files exist for two separate purposes.

- `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini`

  This file will be used by your web server. So running `phpinfo()` in a PHP file that gets served by your web browser, will show you this ini file.
- `/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini`

  This file will be used by the command line (CLI is an acronym for **C**ommand-**L**ine **I**nterface). So running commands in the CLI will, in fact, use this `ini` file and not the other one. It should be possible to verify this by running `php -i` in the command line (I don't have PHP installed on the OS I'm currently using in order to test the command).

So as you can see, if for example, you enable an extension in the `fpm/php.ini` because Magento needs it, you will find that the `magento` CLI command would fail and complain if you don't also enable that module in the second file as well.
(It may be a better idea to enable PHP extensions in another way, like `php7.2enmod` in Ubuntu, but this is just an example)

Comment: Thank you very much for your master class! I was going crazy because it is what you say, since the phpinfo () it appeared to me that it used the /fpm/php.ini and from the php --ini it appeared to me that it used the /cli/php.ini. Therefore, it is normal to edit both files with the configuration that Magento needs (the same information in both files), right?

Comment: There are some cases where you don't need to have the exact information in both of the files (like memory allocation for example), but more often than not, you want to edit both files.

Answer (score 2):

check `phpinfo();`

you will see **"Configuration File (php.ini) Path"** in info list, this is where you find **php.ini** file path

Comment: Yes but when I created the fie, I have this error: 404 error: Page not found php

Comment: This is because of your magento .htaccess file. For testing purpose, you need to edit your project index file. `pub/index.php` and add `phpinfo();die;` there on top of the file

Comment: Welcome..... :)